# S3 Access Denied when getting objects from CloudTrail S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I use the cloudtrail bucket to make Athena queries and I keep getting this error:

> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: A57070510EFFB74B; S3 Extended Request ID: v56qfenqDD8d5oXUlkgfExqShUqlxwRwTQHR1S0PmHpp7WH+cz0x8D2pPLPkRoGz2o428hmOV1U=), S3 Extended Request ID: v56qfenqDD8d5oXUlkgfExqShUqlxwRwTQHR1S0PmHpp7WH+cz0x8D2pPLPkRoGz2o428hmOV1U= (Path: s3://cf-account-foundation-cloudtrailstack-trailbucket-707522222211/AWSLogs/707522222211/CloudTrail/ca-central-1/2019/01/11/707522222211_CloudTrail_ca-central-1_20190111T0015Z_XE4JGGZLQTNS334S.json.gz)
>
> This query ran against the "default" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 56a188d5-9a10-4c30-a701-42c243c154c6.

The query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "default"."cloudtrail_table_logs" limit 10;
```

This is the S3 bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cf-account-foundation-cloudtrailstack-trailbucket-707522222211"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cf-account-foundation-cloudtrailstack-trailbucket-707522222211/AWSLogs/707522222211/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The S3 bucket is in the region eu-central-1 (frankfurt) same as the athena table from which I make the queries.

I have administrator permissions on my IAM User.

I get the same error when I manually try to open a file in this bucket:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>5D49DF767D01F32C</RequestId><HostId>9Vd/MvDy5/AJYExs6BXoZbuMxxjxTCfFqzaMTQDwyrgyVZpdL+AgDihiZu3k17PWEYOJ19I8sbQ=</HostId></Error>
```

I don't know what is going on here. One more precision is that the bucket has SSE-KMS encryption but that does not mean we can't make queries into it.

Same error even when I put the bucket on public.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Is the bucket in the same account, or are you using a second account to store logs?

Comment: everything is in the same account